# Is there a way to make multiple files open in separate windows with a bash command?

Tags: bash, applescript

I want to make a simple bash script that will open up 4 different text editor windows in 4 separate desktop spaces on my Mac.

The closest solution I have is to transition the desktop by triggering an apple script between each atom call (atom is the text editor I'm using.) Right now it looks like this

```
prepare() {
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 18 using command down"
  atom spec
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 19 using command down"
  atom db
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 20 using command down"
  atom app
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to key code 21 using command down"
  atom app/assets
}
```

The apple script triggers a keyboard click (Command 1, command 2, etc) which I have set up in settings to open a specific desktop space.

The problem is that atom opens in whichever desktop is open when it finishes loading, not when it starts. So each atom window opens in a random space based on how long it takes to load and which line of the bash command was just executed.

How can I get the functionality I need? Open to solutions that are totally different from the way I have it set up. I just need something to open 4 seperate atom windows in 4 different desktop spaces. Don't care how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You may provide more info about your system/environment since not all commands or tools are universal.

I actually don't know what your "desktops" exactly mean. As far as I understand, it seems that you want your 4 editors open on 4 different "screens" (which you can switch manually, on MAC OS, not 4 positions dividing the same screen) but in a specified order.

On this point, I don't know either how `atom` is executed. Check its manual may help you on specifying the "desktop"; if not, you may try to check the process(es) or even memories invoked by `atom` whether it has an identifiable signal after "loading" and before "open a window on a screen".

e.g. You may find that `atom` first creates a process say "loading", then another, say "open". In this case, you can wait until the "loading" process ends:

```
atom app & wait
```

If it's not the case, you may simply `sleep` for some seconds enough for the "loading" step of an editor ends. But this is not reliable anyway.